Google's "browse by name" or `gfns` query parameter
For over 8 years I've been using gfns parameters (also known by "browse by name" by some plugins) as my default search engine in Chrome/Firefox/Safari. It enabled me to search for a string and if Google could associate it with a specific url with a high degree of confidence it would just send me straight to the link.
Over the last couple of years that search parameter has become more and more unreliable and over the last few months has stopped working entirely.
I'm curious if anyone knows:

why this happened
if this functionality is still accessible, if so, how
if it's not accessible, if there are any alternatives that operate the same way

For 3, I'd like to maintain the same behaviour as now, so:

Searches with high confidence url matches just get directed to (e.g. stackexchange superuser should just go to the website)
Any other search falls back to a Google search

Anyone have any insights/advice?

Here is my answer to question about Google search operators.

Thanks Rubén, this question isn't about an operator per se, but a query parameter you can attach in the url of the search request.

Here are answer and answer to questions about Google (search) query strings. The previous link might be more interesting as it includes links to several dated sources.

Is that the "I'm Feeling Lucky" search parameter?

@galacticninja I believe it was something to do with that. But I'm not sure if "I'm feeling lucky" did a confidence based fallback to a search page. Are you aware of any parameters that might enable that functionality that I can test?

This question is also posted on [su]. Q1861677

@Blindspots Why was this question closed for needing clarity? What is it missing?

@rbhalla I suggest that you post a query on Web Apps SE Meta about the closure of this question so that you can get some clarification on why it was closed and seek feedback or discuss it with the community.

There are a few issues with the question.  Including detail, question focus, browser config vs web app question.  As a starting point, I would look at the feedback you received on your duplicate on Super User and improve that question.

Respectfully, the question on the duplicate post showed a misunderstanding of how search APIs work. Using it to justify closing this question seems harsh, because it implies their lack of understanding is my failure. In an advanced user forum my hope is that questions are responded to by people who have some base knowledge on the topic, not the opposite. Also, the focus on a single question feels pedantic. You only have to look at a bunch of recently answered questions to see optimistic follows up like "why" is commonplace. Not sure why it's particularly detracting here.

That wasn't an attempt to reopen the question, since I'm having way better experiences on other forums with this particular question, but I just wanted to provide some feedback in case it's helpful.
